# Materialized View PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, materialized-view, postgresql-9.2

Is there any possibility of having built-in materialized views in PostgreSQL ?

I don't want Gardner version or somehthing like physical table populated by triggers.
I've read that was/is something being deploy...

Comment: It's being developed now,may be will come trun in PostgreSQL 9.3. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html

Comment: There is possibility to delivery a beta version?

Comment: of course when the beta's start hitting... or you could just build from source...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A basic version of materialized view are being delivered in 9.3, see [depesz's article](http://www.depesz.com/2013/03/04/waiting-for-9-3-add-a-materialized-view-relations/). However, it's a very limited version as you have to call `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` to get the database to update the view. This will hopefully improve to become automatic in later versions soon.

Comment: It has been improved in 9.4, so you can REFRSH the view concurrently now, if it has any UNIQUE index. See depesz's article: http://www.depesz.com/2013/07/22/waiting-for-9-4-add-support-for-refresh-materialized-view-concurrently/